# android canvas animate background?

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to animate a background in a game I'm making.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvSZc.jpg
Should look like this(terrible recording quality)
My first attempt work well on my phone but a lot of people saw their fps cut in half:

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    if (mPaint == null) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(canvas.getWidth() / 4, canvas.getHeight() / 3,
            Math.max(1, canvas.getHeight() / 2), Color.rgb(5, 12, 127), Color.rgb(32, 36, 100), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    }
    width = canvas.getWidth();
    height = canvas.getHeight();
    canvas.save();
    rotation += 4;
    if (rotation > 360)
        rotation = 0;
    canvas.rotate(rotation, width / 2, height / 2);
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, height * 1.3f, mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

So now I'm thinking about of pre rendering a image and drawing it as a bitmap that covers the screen and rotates instead. I also cut the calculations to only update every other frame instead.

```
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    if (!initiated) {
        centerX = (int) (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        centerY = (int) (canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        width = (int) (canvas.getWidth() * 2f);
        height = (int) (canvas.getHeight() * 2f);
        map = factory.GFX().getBackground();
        initiated = true;
    }
    if (!skipUpdate) {
        x = CalculatorService.getXCircle(rotation, distance, centerX);
        y = CalculatorService.getYCircle(rotation, distance, centerY);

        body.set((int) x - width / 2,
            (int) y - height / 2,
            (int) x + (width / 2),
            (int) y + (height / 2));
        rotation += rotationSpeed;
        if (rotation > 360)
            rotation = 0;
    }
    skipUpdate = !skipUpdate;

    canvas.drawBitmap(map, null, body, paint);
}
```

Though since the image is small in size 320*320 I had to scale it up and draw it bigger then the screen to avoid it moving out of bounds and showing the basic black background, and I'm not sure if this is really a improvement, do anyone have a better way of doing it or any advice on how I can improve?

Comment: Consider using [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) which is backed by OpenGL.

Comment: The whole thing is based on a SurfaceView with preference to getting a hardwareCanvas, not sure how much work it would be to convert all to OpenGL since everything else is working fine as it is

Comment: Are you trying to fix the actual FPS number, or do you want to fix gameplay so that the perceived _speed_ stays the same, even when frames are dropping? Also, I think you should critically compare the amount of time saved by the `skipUpdate` logic to the amount of time it takes to execute that `drawBitmap()` call.

Comment: I would like it to stay as close to 60 fps as possible, I find in unreasonable for this feature to drop it to around 30 for some of my users. Yeah it was a desperation move, not sure if it does much at all

Comment: It's not really clear why this would be unable to make 60fps, even on low-end phones. I just can't believe drawing a 320x320 bitmap would take that long. I suspect the problem is in code not posted here.

Comment: The solution with drawing a bitmap is just a suggestion I have that I wanted to try, the first code is the one that is slowing down everything

Comment: Create a bitmap dynamically, at run time, and oversize it, such that no black area will ever have to be shown. Don't _scale_ it, just _translate_ it. It looks like you've already figured out how to avoid the need to _rotate_ it.